# how to auto-fill a rich text box by selecting a item in drop-down list in InfoPath

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-online

i am making a form by infoPath. i wanna make a function which is :

- i got two lists named 'Support Requests' and 'Feather Stories'.

'Support Requests' got two columns  called 'title' and 'content'.

'Feather Stories'  got a column called 'content' too.(there are more than one column)

- a drop-down list And a rich text box  in Feather Stories's infopath form.
- i want this : when i  select a item "title 1"(there is 'title 1 in Feather Stories's title') in this drop-down list , and that rich text box will be auto-filled by Feather Stories' Correspondingly 'content' .

in short ,  i want the rich text box be auto-filled with data from other list in sharepoint when i select a certain item the drop-down list .